# Is $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Is $f(x) = \log(1+x^2)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

**My work:**
Looking at the graph and knowing that $\log$ considered a "slow-growing" function, my guess is that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and  $\left| {x - y} \right| < \delta $ where $\delta$ will be defined later.

$$\left| {f(x) - f(y)} \right| = \left| {\log (1 + {x^2}) - \log (1 + {y^2})} \right| = \left| {\log \left( {{{1 + {x^2}} \over {1 + {y^2}}}} \right)} \right| \le {{1 + {x^2}} \over {1 + {y^2}}}$$

The problem is that the last expression is too large.
I tried assuming $x < y$ (without loss of generality).
Also, I tried multiplying by $(1-y^2)$ but nothing good came out from that.

What am I missing?

**Update**:
I'm not allowed to use the fact that the derivative is bounded which implies uniform continuity. I'm suppose to prove it "directly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ (i.e., is continuously differentiable), and its derivative is bounded. Hence, it is Lipschitz.

Another approach (following the edit of the original question -- "Lipschitz-ness is not allowed"):
 suppose wlog that $\epsilon \leq \frac{1}{2}$, and let $\delta\stackrel{\rm{def}}{=}\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Fix any $x \geq y$ with $\lvert x-y \rvert \leq \delta$. Then
$$
1 \leq \frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2} \leq \frac{1+(y+\delta)^2}{1+y^2} = 1+\delta \frac{2y+\delta}{1+y^2} \leq 1+\delta \frac{1+2y}{1+y^2}
$$
so that
$$
\ln 1 \leq \ln \frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2} \leq \ln\!\left( 1+\delta \frac{1+2y}{1+y^2} \right)
$$
Now, using the "fact" (easy to prove) that for every $y > 0$ one has $\frac{1+2y}{1+y^2} \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \leq 2$, you get
$$
0 \leq \ln \frac{1+x^2}{1+y^2} \leq \ln(1+2\delta)\leq 2\delta = \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Sadly, although I know that fact we are not allowed to use it yet.

Comment: Just edited to add another approach, then.